# Acumatica , modify Generated Gl batch from so invoice to handle multi payments

Tags: acumatica

i added Mix Payments Tab in So Invoice Screen to handle multi payments issue in cash sale 
[So Invoice with Multi Payments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9h9XJ.jpg)
Then i customized Released Button in SoInvoice Screen to Modify in GL batch generated
But i have the next problems.
1- Issue doesn’t release Automatic after release invoice .
2- I added only some records in GL batch but i couldn’t delete any record .
(I need to delete one record from generated GL batch)
3-In database table (GlTran) after I added some recorded , I notice four columns with different values
[Sql pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFA3U.jpg)

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
```

{

```
public class SOInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<SOInvoiceEntry>
{
    public delegate IEnumerable ReleaseDelegate(PXAdapter adapter);
    [PXOverride]
    public IEnumerable Release(PXAdapter adapter, ReleaseDelegate baseMethod)
    {
        PXGraph.InstanceCreated.AddHandler<JournalEntry>((JournalEntry graph) =>
        {
            graph.GetExtension<JournalEntry_Extension>().RefNbrmix = this.Base.Document.Current.RefNbr;
            graph.GetExtension<JournalEntry_Extension>().DocTypemix = this.Base.Document.Current.DocType;
            graph.GetExtension<JournalEntry_Extension>().ModifyBatchFromAP = true;

        });

        return baseMethod(adapter);
    }

}
```

}

namespace PX.Objects.GL
{

```
public class JournalEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
{
    [PXOverride]
    public void Persist(Action del)
    {

        if (ModifyBatchFromAP)
        {
            string RefNbr = RefNbrmix;
            string DocType = DocTypemix;
            decimal? Total = 0;
            ArrayList tran = new ArrayList();
            PXSelectBase<MixPayments> nonStk = new PXSelectReadonly<MixPayments, Where<MixPayments.refNbr, Equal<Required<MixPayments.refNbr>>, And<MixPayments.docType, Equal<Required<MixPayments.docType>>>>>(this.Base);
            nonStk.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
            PXResultset<MixPayments> resultNonStk = nonStk.Select(RefNbr, DocType);
            foreach (MixPayments nonStkItem in resultNonStk)
            {
                var glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.accountID>(glTran, nonStkItem.AccountID);
                glTran = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.subID>(glTran, nonStkItem.SubId);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.curyDebitAmt>(glTran, nonStkItem.LineAmount);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.debitAmt>(glTran, nonStkItem.LineAmount);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.tranType>(glTran, DocType);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.refNbr>(glTran, RefNbr);
                Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran);
                Total = Total + nonStkItem.LineAmount;
            }

            var glTran2 = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Insert();
            Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.accountID>(glTran2, "1301056");
            glTran2 = Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran2);
            Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.SetValueExt<GLTran.subID>(glTran2, "HDM0000");
            glTran2.CuryCreditAmt = Total;
            glTran2.CreditAmt = Total;
            glTran2.TranType = DocType;
            glTran2.RefNbr = RefNbr;
            Base.GLTranModuleBatNbr.Update(glTran2);
        }

        del();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question, add the code as text, add some explanation about the process that you are trying to implement and the issue that you are facing. Right now the question is unclear.

Comment: i did , thank you for support